# How do I configure postfix to deliver mail for specified domains to another host, and deliver the rest using MX records

Tags: postfix

We currently have postfix handling emails generated by a number of apps. A number of these emails are destined for users inside the organisation, whose mail is on an Exchange server in the same site as the postfix box.

I'm looking for a way to do this, but my Google-fu is letting me down:

If the recipient domain is one of our domains, deliver the mail to host mail.example.com. All other mail is delivered by looking up the MX record/s and processing normally.

**Edit**: to clarify, the apps generating the emails are sending to users outside of our organisation too, postfix is not receiving mail at all.

Comment: [http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html](http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html) looks promising

Comment: I'm reading that right now. I also have a headache right now and I'm reasonably certain that's not a coincidence. :-) Was hoping someone had a quick answer that could save a bit of trial-and-error.

Comment: Graeme, I know a quick and easy solution with exim: hubbed hosts. Regarding this matter, Postfix is somewhat more picky about who its friends are :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instructions work for Ubuntu, you may need to adjust for other distros.

Add the following to /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
relay_domains = domain1.com, domain2.com
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
relay_recipient_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relay_recipients
relay_transport = relay
```

Create the file /etc/postfix/transport:

```
domain1.com  smtp:[mail.example.com]
domain2.com  smtp:[mail.example.com]
```

Create the file /etc/postfix/relay_recipients:

```
@domain1.com x
@domain2.com x
```

Run these commands:

```
$ sudo postmap /etc/postfix/transport
$ sudo postmap /etc/postfix/relay_recipients
$ sudo /etc/init.d/postfix reload
```

Comment: [Patrick Ben Koetter and Ralf Hildebrandt concur](http://postfix.state-of-mind.de/patrick.koetter/mailrelay/#d0e257).

Comment: Working link from @JdeBP's comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20190630072416/http://postfix.state-of-mind.de:80/patrick.koetter/mailrelay/

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like your postifx box is acting as a secondary MX (with Exchange as the primary). Just [configure it as such](http://www.akadia.com/services/postfix_mx_backup.html).

Comment: No it only relays mail, it doesn't receive.

Comment: What is it relaying if it doesn't receive mails? Assuming you mean that it's not exposed on the network as a secondary MX, that doesn't matter (just skip the steps for the DNS config)

Comment: It doesn't "receive" in the sense that it's not listed as the MX for anything. It receives mail from various app servers and delivers it to the destination.

Comment: So its a secondary MX