# How to ensure postfix delivers e-mail without looking locally first

Tags: postfix

I'm using postfix server with webmin, which means my web server is on the same machine.

My mail setup is as follows: I have an external e-mail solution (paid for per mailbox) which I use and thus the MX records etc are setup correctly to go there.

However I also have setup a local mailbox for the domain in question so that I can send e-mails from the local webserver securely and automatically via a web app. This is reflected in the SPF records.

The problem now is when I send e-mails using the local server to my own domain. Postfix tries to look locally first because I have setup a local mailbox. But I don't want that to happen as the real mailboxes are in the external server.

Where do I have to look and what do I have to do in order to setup postfix using webmin so that it will either:

1. don't look locally for certain domains even if there is a mailbox locally
2. don't look locally whatever the domain even if there is a mailbox locally.

Comment: It will be helpful to post your current config.

Comment: I strongly agree with Khaled. Please give us the results to the command ```sudo postconf -n``` to show us the non-default configuration settings.

Comment: Your configuration is screwed up. This must be corrected.

Comment: This question contains a solution that may apply to your problem: http://serverfault.com/questions/280585/how-do-i-configure-postfix-to-deliver-mail-for-specified-domains-to-another-host

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell exactly what the issue is without seeing your current configuration (please post us results from `sudo postconf -n`), but I just went through an issue just like what you explain, except minus webmin.

Out of the possibilities I am aware of, one or more of the following could apply:

- you have a virtual alias setup in `/etc/postfix/virtual` that is causing mail redirection (to a local relay perhaps). If you change virtual, make sure to call `sudo postmap /etc/postfix/virtual` to map your changes into postfix.
- mydestination variable in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` includes your server hostname. This was the issue I had, actually. By removing this (I left it equal to `mydestination = localhost.localdomain, localhost`) I was able to regain my sanity. Note that after making any changes to main.cf, you must call `postfix reload` to reload your changes into postfix.

For reference: http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html